# A continuous function on a disk taking values $1,-1$ at ends

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $D^2 = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it possible to construct a continuous function $f:D^2\rightarrow [-1,1]$ such that

$f(-1,0)=-1$,

$f(1,0)=1$, and

$f(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $(x,y) = (0,0)$?

Comment: If this was one dim. $f(x)=x$ would work. Can you extend the result to 2 dimensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, on any path from the point $(-1,0)$ to the point $(1,0)$, $f$ must yield all values between $-1$ and $+1$, so on any such path not going through $(0,0)$, $f$ must yield a zero value somewhere on the path.

Explanation:

A path is a connected set, and the continuous image of a connected set is connected. But any connected subset of $[-1,1]$ containing both $-1$ and $1$ must be the entire interval, and in particular, must contain $0$.